# can someone explain to me why i get an Uncaught TypeError: cannot set property of null

Tags: javascript

```
(function() {
        var myFunc = {
             init : function() {
                alert("I need");
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "help";
            }
        };
window.myFunc = myFunc;
})();
myFunc.init();
```

The alert() message works but the Uncaught TypeError is thrown when it reaches the next line. Can anyone explain to me why and how to fix it? I assume it is something to do with the scoping of the function as it will work if nested within the myDiv rather than the linked .js file.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing looks wrong with your code. Which browser is it failing in? I tried it in FF4, IE8, and Chrome9. They all worked. http://jsfiddle.net/PffYx/

Comment: its in chrome. the alert works fine which is why i cant understand why it gets that far but wont set the innerHTML

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is executing before the document is parsed.

You should move the `<script>` tag to the bottom of the document, or call `init` in the `onload` event.

Comment: I tried moving the script tags to the bottom of the page but it didnt help and tried calling window.onload = myFunc.init(); but it didnt wqork either

Comment: Please show us a demo.  Also, your second line calls it immediately, then assigns the return value to `onload`.  Change that to `window.onload = myfunc.init;` (and beware of `this`)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/PffYx thats a demo of it there but its when tryin to run it from the linked .js file that it wont work. it does work if i add the code within the "myDiv" but i want to keep it in a separate file

Comment: @user: Move your `<script>` tag to the bottom of the file so that the script will only execute after the HTML is parsed.

Comment: i'm not really sure why, but moving the script tags to the bottom didnt work so i wrote a document ready function instead to stop the script from executing before the document was parsed. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

is document.getElementById("myDiv") returning null?